# Prevent google drive editor download file - google enterprise

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I want that some users into google drive shared drive join and edit files, but without any option to share file (sharing, download, print, etc).

Its possible to modify "Editor" role permissions to have a custom setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict editors from sharing the file by following this [article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893).

Screenshot:

Click on the Gear Icon on the upper right

[image]

You can uncheck these options below

[image]

But unfortunately, for restricting editors to download or copy a file, that isn't currently possible. I'd suggest you submit a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106).

Also, if you do have a Google Workspace account, there are settings within the Admin Console that you can configure to restrict sharing outside of the organization. You can read more [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781).